# overlap fix navigation with jQuery validation input error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I work with jQuery validation plugin and bootstrap. I put fix navigation in top page using bootstrap css. Now I need to validate first input, jquery validation worked But fix navigation overlapped with input validation error and error hide(I checked In FF 30).

JS:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

problem pic:

[image]

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/1422/

Comment: it is working fine, here.. FF 30(linux)

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt: it's worked fine in chrome! but in FF 30 windows not worked !

Comment: strange.. I think you will have to manually inject some padding to the area. Because It is working fine in all browsers I am having..

Answer (score 0):

Please add some padding to the body I hope that would fix this.
OR
Try some logic with jQuery that if the error message exists in the dom add the padding to the body else don't.